# Multiple spring batch jobs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using the @Scheduled annotation in Spring Boot to trigger multiple jobs.

Following is the code snippet:

```
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    @EnableScheduling
    public class Config extends DefaultBatchConfigurer{

            @Autowired
            JobLauncher launcher;

            @Scheduled
            public void run(){
            String[] argList = {"A", "B"};
            for(String char : argList){
                launcher.run(job(), 
                new JobParametersBuilder().
                addString("char", char).
                toJobParameters());
               } 
             }

       public Job job(){
       //Job definition is here.
       }
    }
```

However, this triggers the 2 jobs in succession and not in parallel, i.e. the application waits for job with parameter "A" to complete before starting job with paramater "B".

Is there a way I can run these jobs in parallel?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the default `JobLauncher`?  If so, it's synchronous by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your `JobLauncher` in some config file and set `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` as task executor which will run jobs async (not waiting for one to complete in order to start next one).

Here is code snippet from :

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
    final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
    return jobLauncher;
 }
```