# How to run parallel jobs in spring batch

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, parallel-processing, spring-batch

I want to run **jobs in parallel**. I am using `Java` configuration. 
I have tried many solutions from here:-
[using spring batch to execute jobs in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347084/using-spring-batch-to-execute-jobs-in-parallel)

[How to run spring batch jobs in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137215/how-to-run-spring-batch-jobs-in-parallel)

I have imported two different `Job` which has `incrementer`, `listener`, `flow`, and
`flow` has single `step`, which then includes `reader`, `processor`, `writer`, in `BatchConfiguration` file.
I also have `Scheduler` where I have added `JobLauncher` so as to run jobs asynchronously by using `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` followed from this link - [Multiple spring batch jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332722/multiple-spring-batch-jobs), along with this I have set `ConcurrencyLimit` to `2` as I have two `Jobs` and also added `@Qualifier("asyncJobLauncher")` when autowiring `JobLauncher` in `BatchConfiguration` followed from this link - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1655
I am able to execute the `jobs` one after the other but not parallel.

But none of the code is working.
Please help me out.

UPDATE:- Below is the sample code

```
@Bean
    public Job importUserJob1() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob1")
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();

@Bean
    public Job importUserJob2() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob2")
                .flow(step2())
                .end()
                .build();
```

Each job `importUserJob1` and `importUserJob2` has separate `step1` and `step2`. And I want to run `importUserJob1` and `importUserJob2` parallel.

Please tell me the way how to achieve it.

Comment: Could you high level summary what you want to achieve?

Comment: @NghiaDo : I have updated my question, added code. Please help me out.

Comment: Thinking, each job has 1 step? Why don't we use 'parallel steps' provided by Spring Batch? http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html

Comment: @NghiaDo : Example:-
If I have two CSV files and I am reading each record ,processing it using and writing it into database. I can scheduled these jobs at different times and these jobs run successfully. 1st files I am reading in `importUserJob1` ,2nd file I am reading in `importUserJob2` having everything different such as its step1 and step2 and step1 and step2 contain its own reader, processor and writer. And I cannot run these two jobs `importUserJob1` and `importUserJob2` in parallel. I do not want to run parallel steps. Please tell me the way how can I achieve this?

Comment: uhm ... I'm a bit not clear. Anyway why can you schedule importUserJob1 and importUSerJob2 at the same time? What scheduler you are using?

Comment: I am scheduling these two jobs as below:-

`@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduling.job.cron1}")
 public void perform() throws Exception {
      
JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("firstName",
                 String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();
      JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(importUserJob(), param);
      JobExecution execution2 = jobLauncher.run(importUserJob2(), param); 
}`
The execution does not got to importUserJob2. It first completes Job1 and then job2.

Comment: I am scheduling tasks in Spring is by creating method annotated by `@Scheduled` in spring managed bean and also by adding `@EnableScheduling` and `@Configuration` in  `BatchScheduler` class.

Comment: Our application wants to do multiple Jobs processing  <br/> 
e.g: Job1-> Do Student File Processing  <br/>
Job2-> Do Employee File Processing  <br/>
Job3-> any other Processing  <br/>  <br/>
These jobs does not have any resemblance to each other so have to run independent of each other but Definitely not one after another.  <br/>
All Jobs to be run in parallel.