# Run parallel jobs in Spring Batch

Tags: parallel-processing, spring-batch, jobs

I want to run **jobs in parallel**. I have tried many solution from below links:-

[using spring batch to execute jobs in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347084/using-spring-batch-to-execute-jobs-in-parallel)

[How to run spring batch jobs in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137215/how-to-run-spring-batch-jobs-in-parallel)

What I want is- 
I have 3 Jobs doing different processes as follows:-
(I have n jobs. But for now 3)
Job1->Do Student File Processing

Job2->Do Employee File Processing

Job3->any other Processing

These jobs does not have any resemblance. They are independent of each other. All jobs to be run in parallel. Below is the sample code:-

`@Bean
    public Job importUserJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener())
                .flow(stepOne()).end().build();
    }`

`@Bean
    public Job importUserOtherJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserOtherJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener())
                .flow(stepSecond()).end().build();
    }`

Similarly, I have two step:-

`stepOne` -> reader, processing, and writing in database and

`stepSecond` -> reader, processing, and writing in database

But, this job does not run in parallel. The second job waits for the first one to complete. I want to run in parallel. I also have added `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` to the `JobLauncher` from this link- [Multiple spring batch jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332722/multiple-spring-batch-jobs) and even also added `@Qualifier("asyncJobLauncher")` when autowired to `JobLauncher` from this link - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1655.

Please tell me way to achieve parallel processing of the jobs.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to launch the jobs?

Comment: I have solved that problem. Now I have some other question. Can I schedule n number of child jobs instead of scheduling parent job ? Or is it necessary to schedule parent job for other child jobs ? I am doing XML configuration. Scheduling the job is also done in XML using `task:scheduled-tasks`. Please help me.

Comment: Still need to see the code...